# MVC controller's parameter always null

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

i can't figure out why the username in the controller always returned as null. When i clicked the button, the button works fine and return the member's username.

```
http://localhost:50555/Account/UserDetails/member1
```

In my view

```
<button data-get="/Account/UserDetails/@m.Username">Details</button>
```

In controller

```
    [Authorize(Roles = "Supervisor, Admin")]
    public ActionResult UserDetails(string username)
    {
        var model = db.Members.Find(username);

        if (model == null)
        {
            return RedirectToAction("ManageUsers");
        }

        return View(model);
    }
```

Comment: You say the button works fine and returns the members user name, yet you say its null in the controller.  These statements are seem to contradict each other, or I am misunderstanding.  Can you clarify?

Comment: The default route looks for a parameter called `id`.  Either add a new route to your route table `Account/UserDetails/{username}` or change your button URL code to `data-get="/Account/UserDetails?username=@m.Username"`

Comment: Hello, sorry for confusion. I mean that when i clicked the button the querystring in the address tab works fine, just the controller's parameter always null.

Comment: Thank you tommy!! You are a lifesaver!

Answer (score 0):

You are not taking the value of username from the querystring.  You are expecting a route parameter.  So you will have to specify the route parameter as shown below:

```
[Authorize(Roles = "Supervisor, Admin")]
[HttpGet("{username}")]
public ActionResult UserDetails(string username)
{
    var model = db.Members.Find(username);

    if (model == null)
    {
        return RedirectToAction("ManageUsers");
    }

    return View(model);
}
```

Refer [this documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/routing?view=aspnetcore-3.1) for more details.